# Stripe: How to see which products are selling

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm not sure if stack overflow is the right place to ask this, so my apologies if not.

I have stripe checkout integrated into my site. Users click a buy button on my site, they go to stripe to complete checkout, then they are redirected back to my site to access the item.

I'm trying to see how many of each product is selling each day. I thought it would be easy through stripe's reports dashboard because you can look at any payment intent and see the products associated with the transaction.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in bulk. The stripe help desk told me I had to upgrade to Sigma for custom reports which I reluctantly did... but now they're telling me that it's not possible there either and there's no connection between `payment_intents` and `products`.

This seems like a really basic eCommerce feature, and I'm surprised and frustrated by how difficult this has been. Am I thinking about stripe wrong? Is it not meant for this purpose? Am I supposed to be capturing all this data in my site backend?

I do capture a lot of the data, but there's often small issues with the event webhook that I haven't bothered to fix because I can manually send the product to the customer.

Are there any workarounds or stripe apps that allow access to this information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Handle the event
switch (event.type) {   
  case 'payment_intent.succeeded':

    const paymentIntentSucceeded = event.data.object;

    var sessions = await stripe.checkout.sessions.list({
      payment_intent: paymentIntentSucceeded.id,
    });

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
      sessions.data[0].id,
      {
        expand: ['line_items'],
      }
    );
```

Here it is in `session.line_items.data`

Answer (score 0):

The *Payment Intent* is not connected to specific products.  However, the Checkout Session that gets created to load the Stripe Checkout page does have information about the prices/products in the `line_items` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items).

You could [retrieve a list](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list) of your Checkout Sessions and pass `line_items.data.price.product` in the `expand` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) to get that information and do some nifty reporting yourself.

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for this. Stripe Sigma doesn't give access to the checkout session table, unfortunately, and you also can't download a list from the UI. Looks like I will need to write some code to download this information from their API.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry I generally focus on the API.  Thankfully the code is mostly written for you in the API reference docs.